# How can I move the cursor programatically in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift

If I enter some text in a UITextField, enter text in another UITextField, then tap back in the first one, I want the cursor to be at the end so I can either continue typing or hit backspace. This is slightly complicated by the fact I have the text right justified, so you'd need to be very precise to tap to the right of the existing text.

I have the following code in a Touch Down action for the UITextField. It would be perfect if Touch Up Inside action was available for UITextFields, but that doesn't appear to be the case. This works alright, looking for some suggestions on a more seamless implementation.

Edit: I added changing the tintColor to clear then back to blue, which eliminates the very brief visual of the cursor moving.

```
@IBAction func touchDown(_ sender: Any) {
        Text.tintColor = .clear
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            let newPosition = self.Text.endOfDocument
            self.Text.selectedTextRange = self.Text.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
        self.Text.tintColor = .blue
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer since my edited code above does provide a suitable solution to my inquiry. The delay and the visual of the cursor moving was undesirable, but that was solved by making the cursor clear and changing it back.

```
//default UI blue
let uiBlue = UIColor(red: CGFloat(0/255.0), green: CGFloat(122/255.0), blue: CGFloat(255/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0)) 

@IBAction func Touch(_ sender: Any) {
    Text.tintColor = .clear
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
        let newPosition = self.Text.endOfDocument
        self.Text.selectedTextRange = self.Text.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
        self.Text.tintColor = self.uiBlue
    }
}
```